# Explicitly convert S[] to ILIst<T> in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, type-conversion

The C# 6 Language Specification (ECMA-334 6th ed.) section 6.2.3 states:

> If there is an explicit reference conversion from S to T
> then there is an explicit reference conversion from S[ ] to IList<T>
> and its base interfaces...

However, the following doesn't compile for C# 10.x in VS 2022 (17.3.6) for .NET 6.0:

```
private const int LENGTH = 4;

public class Source { }
public class Target { public static explicit operator Target(Source _) => new Target(); }


static void Main()
{
    _ = (Target)new Source();               // Ok

    _ = (IList<Target>)new Source[LENGTH];  // Error, can't convert Source[] to IList<Target>
}
```

The compiler emits:

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'stack_overflow.Program.Source[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<stack_overflow.Program.Target>'

Comment: *"explicit reference conversion"* - keyword: **"reference"**. Your conversion operator is not a reference conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because what you have is an explicit `user-defined conversion` operator.
A user-defined explicit conversion from a type `S` to a type `T` exists if a user-defined explicit conversion exists from a variable of type `S` to `T`.

For more info about user-defined explicit conversion, check [here (§10.5.5)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1055-user-defined-explicit-conversions).

`Reference conversions` on the other hand are conversions between reference types that require run-time checks to ensure that they are correct. Reference conversions are described [here (§10.3.5)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1035-explicit-reference-conversions).

Answer (score 0):

The conversion operator is a *user-defined conversion*, not a *reference conversion*.